# Which screen resolution is best for reading in 13 inch laptop?

Tags: screen-resolution

I do work with a [13 inch](http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/latitude-e7470/spd/latitude-e7470-ultrabook) laptop for reading and writing. Please suggest which screen resolution is best for eyes.

Resolution:

1360 * 768 (16:9) or
1600 * 900 (16:9)

Comment: Please note that screen resolution does not equel on how big the letters are rendered. A 640x480 screen with 1cm tall letters would have as big letters as a 4k screen with 1cm letters. They just look smoother.

Answer (score 2):

The higher resolution the better it is for your eyes. Looking at pixels is not good for your eyes so you can limit that with high res.

> The higher is always better, but if you can’t find a 4k resolution laptop in your budget or the laptop you want doesn’t have the higher resolution model then stick to at least 1080p resolution.

[Source](https://www.quickfever.com/5752/whats-the-best-resolution-for-a-13-inch-laptop-screen/)